# Flutter Row remove lines

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, containers

I have a Containers in Columns inside in a Row, and the the problem is that some vertical lines are displayed on each side, as a gray color, and I would like to remove it.
This is my container:

```
return Row(
  children: [
    const VerticalDivider(
      width: 30,
    ),
    Column(
      children: [
        const SizedBox(
          height: 20,
        ),
        InkWell(
            child: Container(
              width: 140,
              height: 90,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.purple,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(urlImg),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            onTap: () => {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => PageGame(
                              urlImagen: urlImg,
                              descripcionApi:
                                  descripcionImg,
                              tituloApi: tituloImg))),
                }),
        Text(
          tituloImg,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ],
);
```

And and on the phone it looks like this:

[image]

How could I remove those grey lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines are due to your `VerticalDivider`. You can set its color to transparent:

```
const VerticalDivider(
      width: 30,
      color: Colors.transparent
    ),
```

Comment: or you can replace this widget with `SizedBox` or `Padding` to get some space

Answer (score 0):

make a Flexible widget as a parent of the Column Widget,
your tree will become:

Row<-Flexible<-Column<-Container

Comment: It doesnt work, it gives me an error: in flex `,if (constraintsError != null) {
        throw constraintsError;
      }`

Answer (score 0):

We should use ,
`Divider() = Column(), VerticalDivider = Row()`

```
const VerticalDivider(
            width: 20,
            thickness: 1,
            indent: 20,
            endIndent: 0,
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
```

[Here is the RESOURCE](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/VerticalDivider-class.html)